# Как создать мобильное приложение наподобие MSQRD?

Tags: android, ios, mobile-development, распознавание-образов

хочу создать приложение наложению эффектов, аксессуаров на лицо через камеру, подскажите в каком направлении двигаться, как вообще называется это технологии, распознавание лица, трекинг? может есть какие то готовые решения?

Answer (score 2):

Прочти о компьютерном зрении. Посмотри библиотеки openCV, Dlib. Это помимо родной службы google. Лично мне больше всего понравилась Dlib. Они все бесплатные. Правда с каждой из них могут возникнуть сложности. OpenCV требует умения создавать нативные приложения. Dlib есть адаптированная библиотека 
https://github.com/tzutalin/dlib-android-app , но по хорошему тут нужны те же навыки что и с openCV. Родная служба не дает полноту возможностей присущей двум выше указанным библиотекам. Во всяком случае это было год назад.. В для ознакомления посоветую все таки Dlib.

Comment: Dlib сложновата для меня, попробую ML Kit для начала

Answer (score 0):

вот пример  https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/cognitive-services/face/tutorials/faceapiinjavaforandroidtutorial

незнаю подойдет ли.если без статьи то взять рожу человека  во внутрь квадрата легко,есть несколько бесплатных готовых либ(от самогоже гугла) .а как двигаться уже дальше сорян...примерно так рисуешь bitmap(готовые бороды,прически и.т.п) и  ложишь их во внутрь квадрата  что опреде6лила пред.либа.те нарисовал квадрат вокруг лица ищ камеры.

Comment: по ссылке платный сервис, всего 7 дней триал. От гугла есть ML Kit буду копать в этом направлении, надеюсь это правильное направление